# How to manage SerializationException in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to understand how to manage `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException` in Spring Cloud Stream. If I understood well the `RetryTemplate` is considered only for application errors (occuring in the `@StreamListener`), so even doing a custom configuration for it is useless. I'm wondering what is the best way since with the default configuration, the application is stuck with infinite attempts to read the message. For example an exception of this type while deserializing Avro:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition member.creation_requested-0 at offset 35. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 116
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found string, expecting int
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:292)
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ValidatingDecoder.readInt(ValidatingDecoder.java:82)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readInt(GenericDatumReader.java:503)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:183)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:116)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:222)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:175)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:145)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:134)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:88)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroDeserializer.deserialize(SpecificAvroDeserializer.java:66)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroDeserializer.deserialize(SpecificAvroDeserializer.java:38)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1041)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3300(Fetcher.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1223)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1400(Fetcher.java:1072)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:562)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:523)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1230)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1187)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:747)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:703)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

That is my config:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        accountCreationRequestedSink:
          destination: voxloud.account.creation_requested
          consumer:
            useNativeDecoding: true
      kafka:
        binder:
          autoCreateTopics: false
          brokers: ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESSES}
          consumer-properties:
            auto.register.schemas: false
            schema.registry.url: ${KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}
            value.subject.name.strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy
          producer-properties:
            auto.register.schemas: false
            schema.registry.url: ${KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}
            value.subject.name.strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy
        bindings:
          accountCreationRequestedSink:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                key:
                  deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
                value:
                  deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroDeserializer
```

Comment: Can you provide your application.yml configuration? by default the exception should be retried 3 times and mark the message as processed. if you tuned your configuration and set autoCommitOffset or autoCommitOnError you can get on an infinite loop..

Comment: That's true for application errors (errors occuring into `@StreamListener`), not for serialization errors (messages processed before listener)

Comment: in my case I'm not using avro but when I have error deserialising json the retry is ok!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found some help in [this article](https://jonboulineau.me/blog/kafka/dealing-with-bad-records-in-kafka).
I created a new deserializer like this:

```java
@Slf4j
public class SafeAvroDeserializer extends KafkaAvroDeserializer {

    @Override
    public final Object deserialize(final String schema, byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            return this.deserialize(bytes);
        } catch (final SerializationException e) {
            log.warn("Error during message deserialization", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final Object deserialize(String schema, byte[] bytes, Schema readerSchema) {
        try {
            return this.deserialize(bytes, readerSchema);
        } catch (final SerializationException e) {
            log.warn("Error during message deserialization", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Then of course I had to bind it to my consumers:

```yaml
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.consumer.configuration.key.deserializer: SafeAvroDeserializer
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.consumer.configuration.value.deserializer: SafeAvroDeserializer
```